# Error al inicializar un String Array

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo

estoy creando un programa que me liste el contenido de un archivo, el problema que cuando inicializo mi String array tengo un error que no se reconocer.
Este es el código:

```
        File origen = new File("TEXTO.TXT");


    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
    FileOutputStream destino = new FileOutputStream(new File("COPIADO.TXT"));
    ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(destino);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;


    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {

        oOS.write(buf, 0, len);

    }



    in.close();
    oOS.close();

    String[] destino1 = origen.list();
    for (int i = 0; i<destino1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(destino1[i]);

    }
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ficheros.Ficheros.main(Ficheros.java:37)

    for (int i = 0; i<destino1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(destino1[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Lo que veo es que primero utilizas la variable destino como FileOutputStream y después la intentas utilizar con String[], intenta cambiarle el nombre y prueba.

Comment: `.list()` te regresa una lista de archivos y directorios que se encuentran en el path que mandas como parámetro al declarar `new File (path)`, pero al mandarle un archivo directo como parámetro la función no te regresa nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que ya tiene un objeto con el nombre **destino** y ese mismo nombre se lo está poniendo a el arreglo:

```
 File origen = new File("TEXTO.TXT");


InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
 /*Primera definición*/
FileOutputStream destino = new FileOutputStream(new File("COPIADO.TXT"));

ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(destino);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
 /*Segunda definición*/
String[] destino = origen.list();

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {

    oOS.write(buf, 0, len);

}

in.close();
oOS.close();
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. Tengo otro error con el FOR para listar el contenido de mi archivo. Actualizado la pregunta

Comment: ¿Cuál es la linea 37 de su archivo?

Comment: He actualziado.

Comment: El error NullPointerException se presenta cuando intenta acceder a un indice que no existe de un arreglo.
Verifique con un System.out.println(destino1.length); antes de que entre al for, para ver qué tamaño tiene el array

Comment: Ya lo hice y me pone 8

Comment: En teoría su ciclo está bien, no veo el porqué del error.
Haga lo mismo pero dandole un indice que usted sepa que existe destino1[0];

Comment: Nada, me sale el mismo error

Comment: intente esta manera de recorrer el array:
`for(String e:destino1 ){
        System.out.println(e);
    }`

Comment: Me sale el mismo error, :( :(